# Spring not picking up value defined in properties file

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I have a class with inject attributes like so:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    private final String myValue;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(
        @Value("${config.myValue}") String myValue) {
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }


    @PostMapping("/dostuff")
    public String dostuff(@RequestBody String message) {
      // stuff
    }
}
```

And then I have a config file defined inside `src/main/resources/application.yml` like so:

```
config:
  myValue: "some value"
```

But my IntelliJ (and cmd) tell me the value is not found:

```
 Could not resolve placeholder 'config.myValue' in value "${config.myValue}"
```

Why is my defined value not being recognized? (I tried renaming file to `application-default.yml` and `application.properties` but that didn't help either)

Comment: Do you see this file in the application context configured in IntelliJ IDEA? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html#spring-file-set.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try renaming file as application.properties and define property like below and check if it works?
config.myValue = some value

Comment: thanks, i tried this but it didn't work

Comment: I tried it with a generating a new spring boot project, and it worked for me.
I would suggest to put a debugger and check.